# filter staff user in combo box in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i want to show only staff user in combo box django admin how i most do it.

```
Article(models.Model):
    author = models.Foreignkey(User)
    ...
    # other fields
```

I want only staff user show in django admin combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the choices with the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
from django.conf import settings

Article(models.Model):
    author = models.Foreignkey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True}
    )
    # …
```

This will filter the items if you use a `ModelForm`, or a `ModelAdmin`. This is however *not* enforced at the database, so if you make ORM calls, it is still possible to link the `author` to a non-staff member. But if you use forms, model admins, etc. properly it will thus only present `User`s with `is_staff=True`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: I always use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL but here write User .